# How to write unittest for table row selection using Antd Library in React

Tags: antd, react-testing-library, redux-thunk

I have a react application and I'm using `@testing-library/jest-dom` for unit testing and antd 3.x library for UI design. In one of my UI screen there is a table and a button where the button only enables when one of the row in table is checked. So I wanted to do a unittest for this. So below is my src code,

```
import {Modal, Button, Form, Input, DatePicker, Table, Card, Tooltip} from 'antd';
...
...
return (
  <>
    <Form>
     ...
     <Card>
         <Table
              data-testid={'lift-hold-grid'}
              className="holdListResultsTable"
              rowSelection={rowSelection}
              columns={columns}
              dataSource={dataSourcee}
              components={{
                body: {
                  row: showRestorationTooltip
                }
              }}
            />
     </Card>
     ...
     <div style = {...}>
       <Button data-testid={'lift-hold-button'} disabled={...} onClick={...}>
           Lift Hold
       </Button>
     </div>
    <Form>
  </>
)
```

and below is the unittest

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

function renderWithReduxAndThunk(ui, initialState) {
   const createdStore = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));
   return {
       ...render(<Provider store={createdStore}>{ui}</Provider>),
       createdStore,
    }
}

const changedState = {
   ...
}
it('should enable the lift hold button after checkbox selection and note input', () => {
   const { container, getByTestId } = renderWithReduxAndThunk(<LegalHoldLiftScreen />, changedState);
   const checkBox = container.querySelector('.ant-checkbox-input');
   fireEvent.click(checkBox);
   const downloadButton = getByTestId('lift-hold-button');
   expect(downloadButton).toBeTruthy();
   expect(downloadButton).not.toBeDisabled();
});
```

but this fails with below message

```
● should enable the lift hold button after checkbox selection and note input
  Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element.
```

what am I missing here??

Comment: Where is the button? Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If redux has nothing to do with your question, don't post redux code.

Comment: Could u please check the edited code above?